# how to set an uiview fullscreen dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an app which has two subviews.I wanna double tap the video view(the top one) to make it fullscreen to display video.(By fullscreen, I mean it should be in landscape mode) So how should I do in the method `-(void)handleTapGesture::(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer`? 
  I guess, first of all, I should hide status bar and navigation bar; then rotate the video view to make it landscape left/right programmatically.
  BTW, for some reason, I have to make my app only support portrait mode.Forgive my terrible English, if you don't understand my question clearly, plz leave a comment, thanks.
[image: project build settings]

[image]

Update:
I've hided status bar and navigation bar both, but when I make the video view fullscreen, it seems navigation bar and status bar are still there and my video view cannot move up to the top of the screen!

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

[UIView beginAnimations : @"video full screen" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

self.videoView.frame = self.view.bounds;
moviewGLView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoView.frame.size.width, self.videoView.frame.size.width*3/4);
moviewGLView.center = self.videoView.center;
videoDefault.center = self.videoView.center;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code in your ViewDidLoad() method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnTopView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeTopViewFullScreen)];
tapOnTopView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[topView addGestureRecognizer:tapOnTopView];
```

add the following function

```
-(void)makeTopViewFullScreen
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
           animation:^
                   {
                       topViewHeightConstraint = self.view.frame.size.height;
                       bottomViewHeightConstraint = 0;
                       [self layoutIfNeeded];
                   }
           completion:^
                   {
                       //your code to rotate the topView
                   }
}
```

note that the topViewHeightConstraint and bottomViewHeightConstraint should be outlets connected in IB.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I've disabled auto layout because of [animation problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766467/animated-uiview-returns-back-after-some-specific-actions-are-triggered) and I've updated question. plz check it out.